# Regex Match all the Slashes in String, If a Word Appears Anywhere in String

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all the slashes `/` in a string but only if the string starts with `"..`

This Regex only matches the first slash

```
(?<=['|"]\.\.)(?<=.)*?/
```

Should match

```
"../a/b/c/test.aspx"
"../a/test.aspx"
```

Should Not

```
"/a/b/c/test.aspx"
../a/b/c/test.aspx
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your regex platform?

Comment: Notepad++ is the editor I am using.

Comment: ggorlen, can you suggest a better title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ uses PCRE regex engine, hence you can use this regex:

```
(?:^"\.\.|(?!^)\G)[^/\n]*\K/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DYIHSw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^"\.\.`: Match `"..` at the start
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. `(?!^)` makes sure we're not at the start position.
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `[^/]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that is not `/`
- `\K`: Reset all the matched info
- `/`: Match a `/`